# Implementing Feedback.js with C#

Tags: c#, base64, mailmessage

This relates to this SO question [[feedback.js server api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131022/feedback-js-server-api/14163338#14163338]) ... but I'm hoping to get a bit more detail for a specific platform - in this case C#.

There seems to be very little documentation around the server side of feedback.js. I am hoping to simply send the submitted issue text and screenshot to a C# page and send that via MailMessage - but so far it's proving quite difficult to figure something out. Anyone able to help/advise?

Thanks in advance!

Reference: https://github.com/niklasvh/feedback.js

Comment: Based on the link it sends a `POST` request to the server. Define a static method in your ASPX code-behind (or in any HttpHandler object) and decorate it using the `WebMethod` attribute. Then for the `url` parameter try something like `MyPage.aspx/MyMethod`

Comment: Thanks for chiming in @PoweredByOrange! I get that it sends a POST but I can't figure out what kind of data it's sending or how to capture the screenshot (binary?) data to include in the email.

Any chance you could provide some mock code to explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: I haven't used the API but the answer says `The URL specified in the url is called using the HTTP POST method, with the image in the 'data' parameter. The image itself is encoded as a DOMString`. On the code-behind, look at the `Request.Form["data"]` object which and convert it to whatever image format it's in.

Comment: Thanks for the added detail! I will try this and report back.